# How to install an homebrew formula without updating homebrew itself?

Tags: macos, command-line, homebrew

When I install or reinstall a formula, homebrew automatically update itself before installing the formula.

When working on a slow connection, this is annoying. How can I cancel this automatic update?

Answer (score 121):

According to this [github issue](https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/issues/1670) and to the [man page](https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/blob/master/docs/Manpage.md), the environment variable `HOMEBREW_NO_AUTO_UPDATE` can be set to `1`.

```
HOMEBREW_NO_AUTO_UPDATE=1 brew install <formula>
```

This will stop the homebrew update for this command. If you want to prevent auto update for your shell session, use:

```
export HOMEBREW_NO_AUTO_UPDATE=1
```

to set it permanently, add it to your `~/.bash_profile`. Note that changing this permanently is [discouraged by the developers](https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/issues/1670#issuecomment-267847105).

Comment: This is a contender for the most time-saving answer on stack exchange.

Answer (score 11):

[source](https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/issues/1670#issuecomment-267847105):

> A better alternative may be instead to set `HOMEBREW_AUTO_UPDATE_SECS` to a higher value (the default is to try and update every 60 seconds).

```bsh
export HOMEBREW_AUTO_UPDATE_SECS=<seconds_you_want>
```

Add the command to `~/.bash_profile` to keep the settings for different terminal sessions.

Answer (score -3):

You can also hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> as soon as the

```
Running `brew update --auto-update`...
```

message shows up. That's a short-term hack.

Comment: What does this add to the already existing answer (which wasn't well-received) proposing the same?

Comment: StackExchange ahh comment